# Find out the string is an universal string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is the question asked to me on an interview to find out the universal string by making a function and he asked me to do it with ES6 if there is a better solution then please help me to solve it in better and shorter way. This is the function which will return true if the string is universal string else it will return false

```js
const universalString = (string) => {
  string = string.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase();
  let cherecterLenData = [];

  // array of alphabets
  let alphabetData = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  // filter with array of alphabets
  alphabetData.filter((charecter, charecterIndex) => {
    if (string.indexOf(charecter) != -1) {
      `check if the character present in a -given string`
      // No. of times a character present in a string 
      let stringCherecterLen = string.split(charecter).length - 1;
      if (stringCherecterLen != 0) {
        cherecterLenData.push(stringCherecterLen);
      }
    }
  });

  if (cherecterLenData.every((val, i, arr) => val === arr[0])) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(universalString("Hello Rajat Srivastava How Are You"));
console.log(universalString("aabbcchh llkkuudd"));
console.log(universalString("abbabcbdbabdbdbabababcbcbab")); // false
console.log(universalString("aaccbbddffee")); // true
```

Comment: What's a universal string, exactly? Is it that every character appears the same number of times as every other character? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Reformatted and made a snippet of the OP code.  Does it run correctly?

Comment: Yes it is running correctly. You can test it in jsbin.com just copy and paste this code on jabin.com

Comment: @RajatSrivastava In the future, if your code works but you want suggestions for improvement, use codereview.stackexchange.com, but be sure to check their [on topic page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting and [take the tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Thank you @ggorlen for the help and knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a "universal string" is one in which every alpha character appears the same number of times as every other alpha character in the string.

One way to solve this is by making a frequency counter and then checking that all the values are the same:

```js
const frequencyCount = a => a.reduce((a, e) => {
  a[e] = ++a[e] || 1;
  return a;
}, {});

const universalString = s => {
  const alpha = [...s.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "")];
  const counts = Object.values(frequencyCount(alpha));
  return !counts.length || counts.every(e => e === counts[0]);
};

[
  "aabbcchh llkkuudd",
  "abbabcbdbabdbdbabababcbcbab",
  "aaccbbddffee"
].forEach(e => console.log(e, "=>", universalString(e)));
```